# Prevent double borders around side-by-side elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, border

If you have multiple containers with 1px border, all containers next to each other generate a 2px border. So in order to get rid of that you always set e.g. `border-right: none;` and then add `border-right: 1px;` to the last child to make all containers have 1px border in all sides.

But if you use flexbox `flex-basis` rule to break containers into next line, it breaks whole `border-right` idea, the last container in the line before the break always stays left out with no border.

e.g. in this example I have 5 containers, but I want 4 per line and when it breaks into new line, you can see the `border-right` issue:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
}

.container {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">1</div>
  <div class="container">2</div>
  <div class="container">3</div>
  <div class="container">4</div>
  <div class="container">5</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/45kngj9p/

Comment: the `.container:nth-child(4)` approach is a valid approach but it depends on whether you want always 4 blocks in a line or different number of blocks in a line on different screens. Even if you need you can use the same approach with media queries.

Comment: Is a js solution acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you know how many flex items there are in each row, you can use the `:nth-child()` selector to apply borders to items missed by the main rule.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
}
.container {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container:nth-child(4n + 1) { /* add border to first child in each row */
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">1</div>
  <div class="container">2</div>
  <div class="container">3</div>
  <div class="container">4</div>
  <div class="container">5</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">1</div>
  <div class="container">2</div>
  <div class="container">3</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">1</div>
  <div class="container">2</div>
  <div class="container">3</div>
  <div class="container">4</div>
  <div class="container">5</div>
  <div class="container">6</div>
  <div class="container">7</div>
  <div class="container">8</div>
  <div class="container">9</div>
  <div class="container">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Border:none;` and add `margin-left:-1px;`

```
.container {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-left:-1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score -2):

You can try these solutions:

## 1

Here you don't need the `.container:last-child` styles.

```
.container {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

## 2

This one works for boxes number 4, 8, 12, etc.

```
.container {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: none;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container:last-child,
.container:nth-child(4n) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```